# fill array from dataset

Tags: c#, .net, web-services

I try to fill array from dataset.
Firstly I am creating a class

```
public class BasvuruMaster
{
     public string Tarih { get; set; }
     public string Icerik { get; set; }
     public string RefNo { get; set; }
}
```

Secondly I am creating connection

I can connect to my database but I cannot fill my array.

```
public BasvuruMaster[] BasvuruListele(string TCK)
{
  string stm = "SELECT TARIH,ICERIK ,REFNO FROM TABLE WHERE TCK=@TCK";
  MySqlDataAdapter da = new MySqlDataAdapter(stm, cnn);
  da.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@TCK", TCK);
  DataSet ds = new DataSet();
  da.Fill(ds);
  BasvuruMaster[] BasVurList = new BasvuruMaster[ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count];
    for (int i = 0; i < ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count; i++)
    {
      if (ds.Tables.Count > 0)
      {
        BasVurList[i].Tarih = ds.Tables[0].Rows[i + 1].ItemArray[0].ToString();
        BasVurList[i].Icerik = ds.Tables[0].Rows[i+1].ItemArray[1].ToString();
        BasVurList[i].RefNo = ds.Tables[0].Rows[i+1].ItemArray[2].ToString();
      }
    } 
  return BasVurList;
}
```

What am I supposed to do?

The error message is

> An exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException' occurred in
>   WebApplication1.dll but was not handled in user code

Comment: Can we see the definition of `BasvuruMaster` as well? On which line you get this error? Also; [What is a `NullReferenceException` and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: I edited it.   Now you can see BasvuruMaster.

Comment: I am in trouble in for loop.

Comment: BasVurList[i].Tarih = ds.Tables[0].Rows[i + 1].ItemArray[0].ToString(); this line has problem

Comment: Set a breakpoint. Inspect your dataset. Check the array indices.

Comment: You are missing a BasVurList[i] = new BasvuruMaster() in your code. All entries in your Array will be null first (the default for a class).

Comment: You should exchange your `if`and `for`: first check if a table is available, then access it.

Comment: I set. I can see "ds.Tables[0].Rows[i + 1].ItemArray[0]"  but .tostring() doesn't work

Comment: I can access to table. I cannot fill my array

Comment: @EgemenHALICI: Just for the sake of debug, check the filling process for one class attribute outside of the for loop... What does happen?

Comment: when i=0 , I got this message @Ordenador

Comment: why "Rows[i + 1]" try "Rows[i]"

Comment: I can read data from dataset when I debugging. The problem is .tostring().

Comment: Firstly I wrote Rows[i] , but I couldn't access the data when I am debugging.After I chanced to Rows[i + 1]. Now I can read data but I cannot fill my array

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I try to explain a little bit deeply.

From [Arrays (C# Programming Guide)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9b9dty7d.aspx)

> The default values of numeric array elements are set to zero, and
>   **reference elements are set to null**.

Since you have an array of `BasvuruMaster` (which is a `class` which is a [reference type)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/490f96s2%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) all your elements are initalized to `null`. And since you try to acccess `Tarih`, `Icerik` and `RefNo` properties of a `null` value, that's why you get `NullReferenceException`.

You can initialize all your `BasvuruMaster` elements inside your for loop.

```
BasvuruMaster[] BasVurList = new BasvuruMaster[ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count];
for (int i = 0; i < ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count; i++)
{
      if (ds.Tables.Count > 0)
      {
        BasVurList[i] = new BasvuruMaster(); <-- HERE
        BasVurList[i].Tarih = ds.Tables[0].Rows[i].ItemArray[0].ToString();
        BasVurList[i].Icerik = ds.Tables[0].Rows[i].ItemArray[1].ToString();
        BasVurList[i].RefNo = ds.Tables[0].Rows[i].ItemArray[2].ToString();
      }
}
```

With that line, you initialize your element with `new BasvuruMaster()` and it's properties initialized their default values. (since they are `string`, both `Tarih`, `Icerik` and `RefNo` will be `null` by default)

As Ralf pointed, I think your `ds.Tables[0].Rows[i+1]` should be `ds.Tables[0].Rows[i]` since you *still* try to increment after the last value, you will get index out of range exception.

Comment: Rows[i+1] will still be after the last row. And while you showing how to do it please place the if outside of the loop ;)

Comment: @Ralf Right, I wasn't focused on that part :). Updated.

Comment: Thanks but I still problem.When I try to write thisway, I cannot build it. The message is The type or namespace name "BasvurList" could not be found (are you missing a using directive  or an assembly reference?)

Comment: @EgemenHALICI Sorry. It should be `new BasvuruMaster()`. Fixed.